# Can I create a simple DB browser with VS 2010 like I could with VS 6?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Having recently installed the beta of VS 2010, I'm curious whether anybody knows how to get it to do something that was quite straightforward with VS 6. To create a simple database browser in VS 6, you could create an MFC application using a database view, connected to (for example an ODBC connection. Then, the interesting part. In a normal application, doing a -double-click on the control will bring up a dialog that lets you connect that control to a member variable of the dialog class. In a database application like this, however, it brings up a dialog that lets you connect the control to a field in the database:

[image: DB Field selection in Add Member Variable dialog]

Having done this for the fields we care about, we can build the application (note that we haven't typed in a *single* line of code) and we can browse data from the database:

[image: Browsing live data]

At this point, we have live data being read from (in this case) a SQL Server database, and we can browse through it, modify data, etc. The development is about like we'd used something like Access, but the output is a standalone executable.

How can I do the same (or how close to the same can I get) using Visual Studio 2008 or 2010?

Comment: Wizard support (for MFC, ATL support seems decent) in Visual Studio has gone downhill ever since VC 6. While all the classes are still there - you will need to write your own code to wire them together (for this particular instance), there is no friendly wizard to do it for you.

Answer (score 15):

The last remaining database project templates were removed in VS2008.  Nobody writes code like this in C++ anymore.  C# and VB.NET, their IDEs have very good dbase integration through the server explorer window.  Give it a try, you'll find it easy going.

Comment: Note that you can write .NET code in C++/CLI, if you are really looking for pain. I'd also suggest C# or VB.NET for new code, however.

Comment: C# is unfortunately not the answer to all the problems. Consider for example writing a plugin for Excel. If you go with 3.5 - what happens when there are other 3rd party controls that need 4.0 or 4.5? There is still a place for c++/MFC. Although for a recent project I've gone with straight win32 for the core and am using CEF to host HTML5 widgets for that extra whizz bang effect.

Comment: The in-process side-by-side CLR versioning support is the answer to that.  If you like writing XLLs in MFC and getting CEF built then have at it.  It is however not a commonly available skill and patience anymore and you might well have trouble finding somebody to maintain your product some day.