# Connect and Insert data into a MS Access table using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, database-connection, insert-into

I am working on a project that requires me to perform insert query on an MS Access table. I have been searching everywhere online but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I have to write this for VS2008 and and Visual C++ 6.0. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft-open-database-connectivity-odbc?view=sql-server-2017). Example of connecting to database and executing INSERT query:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

WCHAR szDSN[] = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\users.mdb";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    

HENV    hEnv;
HDBC    hDbc;

/* ODBC API return status */
RETCODE rc;

int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
WCHAR    szConnStrOut[256];

WCHAR* query = L"INSERT INTO [Users] (name,surname) VALUES ('John','Smith');";

HSTMT           hStmt;

/* Allocate an environment handle */
rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
/* Allocate a connection handle */
rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

/* Connect to the database */
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN, 
    SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut, 
    255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
{

    wprintf(L"Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n", 
        szConnStrOut);  

    /* Prepare SQL query */
    wprintf(L"SQL query:\n  %s\n", query);

    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc,&hStmt);
    rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS);   

    /* Excecute the query */
    rc = SQLExecute(hStmt); 
    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) 
    {
        wprintf(L"SQL Success\n");
    }
    else{
        wprintf(L"SQL Failed\n");
    }
}
else
{
    wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s.\n",szDSN);
}

/* Disconnect and free up allocated handles */
SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc811599(v=office.12)

Answer (score 1):

You have (far too) many choices: [ADO/RDO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d27at40d(v=VS.71).aspx), [DAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984815(v=VS.71).aspx), [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ds2ktb(v=VS.71).aspx), and [OLE DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk4h509a%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), to name only a few. DAO is officially deprecated. ADO/RDO aren't officially, but MS doesn't seem to care much about them anymore either. With VC 6, however, obsolescent is pretty much a fact of life. I believe they're all still supported to at least some degree under VS 2008, but they no longer, for example, include any wizards to help with using DAO.

That basically leaves OLE DB and ODBC as your first couple of choices. MS is still actively supporting and developing them, and the others are unlikely to provide any major advantage anyway.

I should add that VC++ 6.0 provides quite a few features missing from VS2008 for writing applications that use databases. You might want to look at what I showed in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211277/can-i-create-a-simple-db-browser-with-vs-2010-like-i-could-with-vs-6) for some guidance.

Comment: What I am looking for, instead of a gui or pop up window as displayed in your question, is simply a working sample code that I can adapt to fit my program specs. The entirety of the program is to read data from an OPC server, KEPware, fetch desired data, then send the results grabbed to and Access table. The code to read the data from the server has been completed. I would prefer to write this in C# however, I do not have the money to buy licenses to use OPC in VS2008 C#. I realize that this is a little long winded but I feel that this gets my point across better.

Comment: @Dante: In that case, you probably don't need the wizards, but the database classes will probably be useful, and make things a lot easier. IMO, the easiest way to get started is to generate a database browsing app with the normal wizards, and then read through the code it generates.