# Connect and retrieve data from a MS Access table using C++

Tags: c++, sql, database, ms-access, odbc

I currently have some code that connects me to the database given in this article here, [Connect and Insert data into a MS Access table using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509000/connect-and-insert-data-into-a-ms-access-table-using-c)
but I need to be able to retrieve data. Lets say I have a table with 1 field, it's called `Names`, and is of type `short text` in Access. There are 5 names within it (or 5 rows I guess) and I need to be able to say `select Names from tbl_Names` and then load the contents of that table's row into an `array` or `vector` of  `char*` or `string`. Here is my current code, I am just missing the part where I actually retrieve the data and store it in the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>



WCHAR szDSN[] = L"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\databaseExample\\databaseExample\\Names.accdb";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HENV    hEnv;
    HDBC    hDbc;

    // ODBC API return status 
    RETCODE rc;

    int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
    WCHAR    szConnStrOut[256];

    const WCHAR* query = L"select Names from tbl_Names";

    HSTMT           hStmt;

    // Allocate an environment handle 
    rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
    // Allocate a connection handle 
    rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

    // Connect to the database 
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (WCHAR*)szDSN,
        SQL_NTS, (WCHAR*)szConnStrOut,
        255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {

        wprintf(L"Successfully connected to database. Data source name: \n  %s\n",
            szConnStrOut);

        // Prepare SQL query 
        wprintf(L"SQL query:\n  %s\n", query);

        rc = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);
        rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLWCHAR*)query, SQL_NTS);

        // Excecute the query 
        rc = SQLExecute(hStmt);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc))
        {
            wprintf(L"SQL Success\n");
        }
        else {
            wprintf(L"SQL Failed\n");
        }

        
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Couldn't connect to %s.\n", szDSN);
    }

    // Disconnect and free up allocated handles
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

    getchar();
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There isn't even a comment either.....

Comment: You can't keep asking essentially the same question over and over again. If you have additions, edit the previous one.

Comment: You probably want something like https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc-tutorial-fetching-results.html

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yeah ive looked at that. I can't find a given example that works for Access DB and the documentation is incredibly confusing for such a simple task that I need. I can't even navigate what functions I need and what they actually do. I was hoping someone knew how to use it.

Comment: SQLFetch gets one row of the resultset.  SQLBindCol tells SQLFetch where to put the data from each column that gets fetched.

Comment: Here's a different example: https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/examples/DescribeAndBindColumns.html  If I find time during the weekend I might write an answer...

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am somewhat getting there understanding each function, bit by bit. I am still stuck on a very initial stage. I don't understand how to connect to the database and then following that use the examples if that makes sense?